# Tabhost + viewPager + ListView; Different value being passed in bundle android

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, android-tabhost, fragmentpageradapter

I have a single listview that is populated with different information depending on the selected tab. What I expect is that historical tab will getPastBookings(), scheduled tab will getFutureBookings() and favorites tab will get getFavoriteBookings().

Unfortunately, historical and scheduled tabs calls getFavoriteBookings OR getFutureBookings, while favorite tab calls nothing.

What could be the problem in the code?

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE. :)

TabsAdapter.java

```
public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
        TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final TabHost mTabHost;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

        static final class TabInfo {
        private final String tag;
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            tag = _tag;
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }    
    }

    static class DummyTabFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {
        private final Context mContext;

        public DummyTabFactory(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View v = new View(mContext);
            v.setMinimumWidth(0);
            v.setMinimumHeight(0);
            return v;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost,
            ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mTabHost = tabHost;
        mViewPager = pager;
        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mContext));
        String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        int position = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
            int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        TabWidget widget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
        int oldFocusability = widget.getDescendantFocusability();
        widget.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
        widget.setDescendantFocusability(oldFocusability);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
}
```

TripsListTabsFragment.java

```
public class TripsListTabsFragment extends BaseSupportFragment {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "TripsListTabsFragment";

    @InjectView(R.id.pager) ViewPager mViewPager;
    @InjectView(android.R.id.tabhost) TabHost mFragTabHost;

    TabsAdapter mTripsPagerAdapter;

    public static Fragment newInstance() {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        TripsListTabsFragment fragment = new TripsListTabsFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return createTabhost(inflater, container);

    }


    private View createTabhost(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_tab_contents, container,
                false);

        ButterKnife.inject(this, rootView);

        mFragTabHost.setup();

        mTripsPagerAdapter = new TabsAdapter(getActivity(), mFragTabHost, mViewPager);

        TabSpec scheduledTab = mFragTabHost.newTabSpec("scheduled")
                .setIndicator(getResources().getString(R.string.scheduled));
        Bundle scheduledTabBundle = new Bundle();
        scheduledTabBundle.putSerializable(TripsListFragment.EXTRA_LIST_TYPE,         ListType.SCHEDULED);
        mTripsPagerAdapter.addTab(scheduledTab, TripsListFragment.class,     scheduledTabBundle);

        TabSpec historicalTab = mFragTabHost.newTabSpec("historical")
                .setIndicator(getResources().getString(R.string.history));
        Bundle historicalTabBundle = new Bundle();
        historicalTabBundle.putSerializable(TripsListFragment.EXTRA_LIST_TYPE,     ListType.HISTORICAL);
        mTripsPagerAdapter.addTab(historicalTab, TripsListFragment.class,     historicalTabBundle);

        TabSpec favoritesTab = mFragTabHost.newTabSpec("favorites")
                .setIndicator(getResources().getString(R.string.button_favorites));
        Bundle favoritesTabBundle = new Bundle();
        favoritesTabBundle.putSerializable(TripsListFragment.EXTRA_LIST_TYPE,     ListType.FAVORITES);
        mTripsPagerAdapter.addTab(favoritesTab, TripsListFragment.class,     favoritesTabBundle);

        setTabColor(mFragTabHost);

        return rootView;
    }

    private void setTabColor(TabHost tabhost) {
        for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++) {
            tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.beck_tab_indicator_ora    nge);
        }
    }
}
```

TripsListFragment.java

```
public class TripsListFragment extends BaseSupportListFragment {

public static final String EXTRA_LIST_TYPE = "com.becktaxi.customer.TRIP_LIST_TYPE";

// @formatter:off
@InjectView (android.R.id.list) ListView mListView;
@InjectView(android.R.id.empty) TextView mEmptyTextView;
// @formatter:on

List<Booking> mBookings;
BookingAdapter mArrayAdapter;

ListType mListType;

public static Fragment newInstance(ListType listType) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable(EXTRA_LIST_TYPE, listType);

    TripsListFragment fragment = new TripsListFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trips_list_layout,
            container, false);

    ButterKnife.inject(this, rootView);

    mBookings = new ArrayList<Booking>();
    ListType lt = (ListType) getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_LIST_TYPE);
    showBookingsInList();

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    showBookingsInList();
}

public void showBookingsInList() {
    if (mArrayAdapter != null) {
        mArrayAdapter = null;
    }

    mListType = (ListType) getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_LIST_TYPE);
    String listType = mListType.name();

    switch (mListType) {
    case SCHEDULED: {
        mBookings = getFutureBookings();
        if(mBookings.size() < 1) {
            mEmptyTextView.setText(R.string.empty_scheduled_bookings);
        }
        break;
    }
    case HISTORICAL: {
        mBookings = getPastBookings();
        if(mBookings.size() < 1) {
            mEmptyTextView.setText(R.string.empty_past_bookings);
        }
        break;
    }

    case FAVORITES: {
        mBookings = getFavoriteBookings();
        if(mBookings.size() < 1) {
            mEmptyTextView.setText(R.string.empty_favourite_bookings);
        }
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
    }

    mArrayAdapter = new BookingAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.view_booking_single_item_layout, R.id.cbv_booking,
            mBookings, mCallbacks.getHelper().getBookingDao());
    setListAdapter(mArrayAdapter);

}

private List<Booking> getPastBookings() {
    try {
        return DbService.getAllPastBookings(mCallbacks.getHelper()
                .getBookingDao());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new ArrayList<Booking>();
}

private List<Booking> getFutureBookings() {
    try {
        return DbService.getAllFutureBookings(mCallbacks.getHelper()
                .getBookingDao());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new ArrayList<Booking>();
}

private List<Booking> getFavoriteBookings() {
    try {
        return DbService.getAllFavoriteBookings(mCallbacks.getHelper()
                .getBookingDao());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new ArrayList<Booking>();
}

public enum ListType {
    SCHEDULED, HISTORICAL, FAVORITES
}

}
```

Comment: consider not using ENUMS in Android.  Create public final ints they are more efficient.  The code is just about the same swith listType where listType is just an int.  case FUTURE:  case PAST: cast FAVORITE.  Not much difference but the code will be smaller and run faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by:

1. Changing `FragmentPagerAdapter` to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`
2. Added `getItemPosition()` in the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` which will return `Position.NONE`
3. Added `notifySetDataChanged()` in `onTabChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

Your sending an empty bundle to your Fragment.

```
public static Fragment newInstance() {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    TripsListTabsFragment fragment = new TripsListTabsFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}
```

Comment: how to use this method?

Comment: Bundles are the standard way of passing information in android.   bundle.putString("name", fullName);
      bundle.putString("email", email);      http://congeritc.blogspot.com/2012/04/android-passing-values-between-views.html